# Junit5 Error. You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I'm trying to develop a parameterized test in JUnit 5, as in the example below.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(ArgClassProvider.class)
void testAction_shouldSmth(ArgClass argClass) {
   //...
}


class ArgClassProvider implements ArgumentsProvider {

    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        return Stream.of(new ArgClass(), new ArgClass()).map(Arguments::of);
    }
}
```

Attempt to run test causes exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ots.platform_sl.service.config.service.EarnMilesServiceTestHotels$ArgClassProvider.<init>()
...
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest
...
```

*You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest*

This message makes me feel, that I'm doing something wrong, am not I?

p. s. I have an assumption, that only args of primitive types are available.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@ArgumentsSource(CategoriesProvider.class)` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. It was a mistake in question text. Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Make `ArgClassProvider` static or a top-level class.

## Long Version

Take a closer look at the error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
com.ots.platform_sl.service.config.service.EarnMilesServiceTestHotels$ArgClassProvider.<init>()
```

What you can see here is that Jupiter can't find a parameterless constructor for `ArgClassProvider`. The reason is that it's [a non-static inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), which means it's implicit constructor takes an instance of the outer class (in this case `EarnMilesServiceTestHotels`) as an argument.

To give your `ArgumentsProvider` implementation [the parameterless constructor it requires](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/#Custom-Argument-Sources), you have two options:

- make it a proper class
- make it `static`, so it no longer references an instances of the outer class and the implicit constructor takes no parameter